# Android Studio issue in release version build

Tags: android

when i build a debug .apk it is works fine and in the manifest file i already given internet permission. Unfortunately when i generate a signed in version it is not working.
Application is showing crash. when i debug got retrofit is not getting response so it going to catch and showing null pointer exception.

Internet permission is given API is not working.

This is my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<application
    android:name=".Controller"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
   <activity
        android:name=".activites.SplashScreen"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Gradle file

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
 }

android {
  compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.motors"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'

// retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
```

}

SOLUTION:

I clear my issue by updating my build.gradle file as mentioned by answered by @Ahmed.
I taught app crash due to network issue but it was not.

```
   buildTypes {
     release {
       minifyEnabled false
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
       optimize.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Even if internet is not working your app should not crash . Add the Crash logs with question looks like problem is somewhere else .

Comment: Yes i thought it is due to internet permission after updating the code minifyEnabled false it work fine

Comment: Disabling pro guard is not the solution here. You need to fix the issue . Add the error stack trace with question. And also add proguard rules with question

Comment: @ADM Error i get while compiling is nullpointer in (try catch) with out try/catch app crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're issue is not about internet permission I guess. But in proguard.
That's the only difference between your Debug build and release build.
You can disable proguard using this instead :

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou After updating these line in code issue has been solved

Answer (score 5):

Issue is not about internet permission. It occurred because you enabled minifyEnabled true. In some cases ProGuard can’t know that a class or method is being used, such as when it’s only referenced by reflection, from XML resources or from JNI code. To prevent that code from being stripped out or renamed, you have to specify additional keep rules in the ProGuard configuration.  You can fix this issues by following:

1. Write rules in proguard-rules.pro for your all network and model classes or package:
   `-keep class com.android.appname.** { *; }`
2. minifyEnabled false